# Event Data Collected by Firebase Analytics DebugView Is Incomplete

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm sending events to Firebase Analytics and find out that part of the event parameters is missing in DebugView.

Below are two identical events sending to Firebase and I've checked that all the parameters are there in Xcode debug console.

[image]
[image]

The missing parameters seem to be random. Sometimes there's no custom param at all, only auto-collected data.

Is there anyone also encounters this problem or does anyone know what causes this?

I'm using FirebaseAnalytics (= 5.8.1)

Comment: Does refreshing the page help?

Comment: No, it doesn't. My colleague emailed to Firebase and they replied to us that this is a known bug.

Comment: Facing same issue, Any help available?

Comment: BTW, if anyone facing that the whole event is not logged, you probably use an event name that  Firebase auto collection has already used. As far as I know, I can't use kFIREventCampaignDetails.

Comment: I am facing same issue but on Android so this is not platform specific issue.

Comment: is there any update for this question???

Comment: We have asked Firebase tech support team again and they replied to us on 8/22 mentioned that this is a cross-team problem and will not be fixed in soon. Bad news.

Comment: Are anyone aware of if this has any influence to actual/real data in the Events view. It's even a bigger problem if it happens to non-debug data too.

Comment: I'm seeing this issue as well. Both in respect to event parameters not showing up and even events and user properties not showing in the timeline. Leaves DebugView not very useful. I usually look at the events in BiqQuery instead as it seems that all is tracked there. You should be able to look up your device in BiqQuery by your Advertising ID (if activated in the connection).

Comment: Just want to throw in a comment from 2021 saying there still seems to be an issue with analytics debug view missing whole events. Is there anyway to verify that the events are actually being collected? I see that http requests are firing off to the /collect backend page, no idea how to check if they actually were collected without debug view.