# Sometimes missing event parameters when using the Android Firebase Analytics SDK

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

The problem I'm facing is that for a given custom event, sometimes certain event parameters are missing in Firebase, even though logcat is showing that everything was submitted correctly. Most notably, sometimes even some of the `firebase_*` and `ga_*` parameters are missing in the DebugView. No errors are showing up in logcat or anywhere else.

The set up is as follows:

- Blaze plan
- 6 custom event parameters in total
- firebase-analytics:17.2.0
- Android API 28
- Not reproducible on iOS, only on Android

Unfortunately I can't provide a MCVE right now, but maybe someone has ideas what could potentially cause this? Is this a bug in the Firebase Analytics SDK perhaps?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671017/event-data-collected-by-firebase-analytics-debugview-is-incomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in the DebugView according to their support. It doesn't affect the actual data, only the DebugView data.

Comment: It does affect data since I don't see all the events in BigQuery.  Some random events are missing